# RegEx Pattern Matching and replace in java, for patterns with Strings I want to ignore in the middle

Tags: java, regex

I have large documents which have some strings in them which look like this:

```
<font face='Greek1'>D</font>
```

These are not full fledged html documents (I know RegEx and html is a big no-no), and they are well behaved on this point.  The values in between `><` are arbitrary.

The documents are large and I need to do a replace across them so that the line:

```
<font face='Greek1'>D</font>
```

looks instead like:

```
D
```

I've written this regex:

```
(<font face='[A-z0-9]*'>)
```

For pattern matching which takes care of the first section, for any face attribute.  The

```
</font>
```

is also pretty easy to code up.

If I have code that looks like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(MYREGEX);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(MYSTRING);
String clean = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

Is there a way to write a single pattern which will find and replace on both the first section:

```
   <font face='Greek1'>D</font>
```

and the second section:

```
   </font>
```

While leaving whatever arbitrary characters are between the >< in place? Or do I have to do these as two seperate reg-exs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I would argue it's not a duplication, based on the types of exclusions.  I want to find and replace on strings, while leaving parts of the replaced content untouched.  The linked question is about a different kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `<font face='[A-z0-9]*'>|</font>` as the regex and it should replace both simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, this would work:

```
String s = "<font face='Greek1'>D</font>";
String value = s.replaceAll("(<.*?>)(.*?)(</.*?>)", "$2"); // D
```

In substance:

- `(<.*?>)` matches the `<...>` part - the `?` is there to prevent that regex from matching the whole string
- the second group is your value
- the third group is the closing tag
- `$2` refers to the second group, i.e. the value

Comment: Thanks, any chance you could explain this a little bit for me?

Comment: Also, is there any performance difference between using the matcher exaple and this replaceAll example on fairly large strings?

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner difficult to comment on performance - you would need to benchmark the various options with actual data to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with *[Reluctant quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)*

```
System.out.println("<font face='Greek1'>D</font>".replaceAll("<.*?>", "")); // D
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I actually want to replace the characters between <> and leave the characters between >< alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non greedy regex and you can do the following:

```
String value = s.replaceAll(".*?>(\\w+)<.*?", "$1");
```

So, it will replace whatever you have `...>D<...` and will keep `D`:

```
<font face='Greek1'>D</font>
```

By only `D`

If you want to only remove the exact text, then you can use:

```
String value = s.replaceAll("<font.*?>(\\w+)</font>", "$1");
```